# como generar una cadena con una F al inicio

Tags: java

generar Folio con un arreglo, se toma de un número entero consecutivo y se convierte a cadena agregando la letra F al inicio y ceros de lado izquierdo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ya intentaste usando printf?

Comment: El código va como texto.

Comment: El código va _como texto, con formato_. No ignores los comentarios ;) Lee [ask]. ¿Cuál es el problema que estás teniendo?

Answer (score 0):

No acabo de entender la pregunta pero si quieres imprimir según el  indice seria algo así

```
System.out.println("CLASE TURISTA");
String[] folio = new String[6];
folio[0] = "F";
folio[1] = "0";
folio[2] = "0";
folio[3] = "0";
folio[4] = "0";
folio[5] = "0";
folio[6] = "0";
System.out.println("Folio :"+ GetElement(5));

function string GetElement(int index){
   string result = "";
   for(var a = 0; a < folio.Count(); a++){
     if(index <= a){
       result = result + folio[a];
     }else{ break; }
   }
   return result;
}
```

Segun el indice que le pases a esa funcion te devolvera unos 0 u otros osea el resultado sera F000000. No se si te servira esto

Comment: la idea en general es hacerlo con un arreglo